# how to fix E: Unmet dependencies in kali linux?

Tags: apt, kali-linux

I did

```
sudo apt-get install wine32
```

And here are the results:

```
root@kali:~# sudo apt-get install wine32
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 metasploit-framework : Depends: postgresql but it is not going to be installed
 wine32:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.28) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libwine:i386 (= 4.0-1) but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: wine:i386 (= 4.0-1)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

How can I fix it?

Here is my linux version:

```
Linux kali 4.9.0-kali3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.18-1kali1 (2017-04-04) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: by the way, i am an otaku. who can make friend with me ???

Comment: Hello and welcome to the Unix and Linux stack exchange site! Please review the [Help Center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) for information on how to best post to this site. Have you tried `apt --fix-broken install` as your error message suggests? Kali Linux, as pointed out in [official documentation](https://docs.kali.org/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux), is not really designed to handle installing whatever. It is pretty much a WYSIWYG style Linux distro.

Comment: and here is my version

Comment: Linux kali 4.9.0-kali3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.18-1kali1 (2017-04-04) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: if the version of Kali Linux that you are using is as old as you say it is you need to upgrade. Your dependencies are missing because they are so far behind what is current. That is the issue with using a rolling release distro is you need to keep some level of parity with updates to maintain a working system. To be honest it may be easier to start over with a fresh install of the latest iso available at kali.org. Backup any important data you have and start over.

Answer (score -1):

First, as the error message describes, you should probably try running:

```
apt --fix-broken install
```

Second, you should confirm that you want to *specifically* install Wine32 and not just standard Wine. It appears that the errors specifically relate to 32-bit dependencies (i386) which, if you're on a 64-bit machine, you probably won't have installed. Alternatively, if you really want Wine32, you could try installing libc6:i386 manually.

Last, I'd mention that Kali isn't really intended for desktop usage. The only reason most users would want Wine on Kali would be for disassembly/reverse engineering. I am assuming, based on that you're asking this question, that that isn't what you're doing.

I would recommend switching to a more desktop focused and beginner friendly distro and using Kali in a VM or as a live-boot tool.

Comment: i have tried it

Comment: but it didn't work

Comment: try running just `sudo apt-get install wine` instead of `sudo apt-get install wine32`.

Comment: i have install wine before

Comment: why are you installing wine32 then?

Comment: when  i  try      wine AoTTG_SLB.exe        

it looks like wine32 is missing, you should install it.
as root, please execute "apt-get install wine32"

Comment: forgive my englis, iam not a native speaker

Comment: uwaaahhhhh i am gonna cry now

Comment: E: Unmet dependencies  again

Comment: I might be leading you into dependency hell here, but try running `sudo apt install libc6:i386 libwine:i386` then `sudo apt install wine32`

Comment: i tried sudo apt install libc6:i386 libwine:i386, and

Comment: E: Unmet dependencies again

Comment: I would recommend.... not doing this on Kali Linux. That said, try running `apt update` and then running the install again.

Comment: hmmmm........., i will try apt-get update

Comment: by the way, arigato~~

Comment: ahhhhh, i am crying now. E: Unmet dependencies again

Comment: Stop using Kali in this way, you're wasting your time. If the issue repeats in ubuntu or Debian, then you have an actual issue, but it won't.

Comment: the whole issue is as described before: it's not up to date. apt-get update && apt-get upgrade (or even apt-get dist-upgrade) should be done first.